# C: Returning char* from a function crashes printf

Tags: c, pointers, return, printf, segmentation-fault

So here's the code containing the `printf` (with line numbers, this is from think.c):

```
30: char *think = getRandomMemory();
31: printf("\33[2K\r");
32: if(think == NULL)
33:     think = "NULL";
34: printf("I have an idea: %s\n", think);
35: parse(think);
36: freeMemory(think);
37: printf("> ");
```

And the code from `getRandomMemory()` which makes sure the returned pointer points to heap allocated space:

```
char *getRandomMemory()
{
    char *ret;

    // --SNIP--

    size_t l = strlen(ret) + 1;
    char *rret = getMemory(sizeof(char) * l);
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        rret[i] = ret[i];
    printf("--- %s ---\n", rret);
    return rret;
}
```

And finally this is what gdb gives me when running this. Please note that the "--- test ---" comes from "   `printf("--- %s ---\n", rret)`" above:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/v10lator/Private/projekte/KI/Lizzy 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Loading Lizzy 0.1... Done!

> --- test ---
[New Thread 0x7ffff781f700 (LWP 32359)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff781f700 (LWP 32359)]
0x00007ffff7869490 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, 
ap=ap@entry=0x7ffff781ee68) at vfprintf.c:1642
1642    vfprintf.c: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7869490 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, 
ap=ap@entry=0x7ffff781ee68) at vfprintf.c:1642
#1  0x00007ffff7919235 in ___printf_chk (flag=1, format=<optimized out>) at printf_chk.c:35
#2  0x00000000004016bc in printf () at /usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:104
#3  run (first=<optimized out>) at think.c:34
#4  0x00007ffff7bc64c6 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff781f700) at pthread_create.c:333
#5  0x00007ffff790a86d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

I really don't know what's wrong here, so hopefully someone sees the mistake.

//EDIT: Forgot the getMemory/freeMemory functions:

```
/*
  * This allocates memory.
  * The difference between usig malloc directly is that this function will
  * print an error and exit the program in case something bad happens.
  */
char *getMemory(size_t size)
{
    char *mem = malloc(size);
    if(mem == NULL)
        crashWithMsg("Internal error (malloc failed)!");
    return mem;
}

/*
 * This deallocates memory.
 * The difference between using free directly is that this function will
 * set the pointer to NULL afterwards.
 */
void freeMemory(void **ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: In `getRandomMemory`: `rret[i] = ret[i];` - `ret` doesn't point to any properly initialized memory, so you have UB (also: `size_t l = strlen(ret) + 1;`).

Comment: You *do* initialize `ret` to a proper string with proper termination?

Comment: Can you tell us (or rather *show* us) what `getMemory` does?

Comment: Yes, ret is initialized. That's just a ton of code, so I snipped it. You can see that it's correct cause of the `printf("--- %s ---\n", rret);` statement, which gets printed successfully.

Will edit the question and add getMemory.

Comment: Unfortunately, seemingly correct behavior is one of the possible results of undefined behavior. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, as it is now it's impossible to do anything but guess.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am trying to create such an example but the code in there (which is nothing but copy&paste) runs just fine, so the verifiable part is where I stuck.

Comment: `char *rret = getMemory(sizeof(char) * l);`?  `sizeof( char )` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf I'm trying to create such an example while we speak but I can't as the example (which is nothing more than copy&pasted code) works like a charm. What I'm doing right now is either removing code from the program or copying from the program to the example but no matter what, the example works while the program crashes.

Comment: Okay, so instead of creating an example I first wanted to get the main program as good as possible, so I used valgrind to detect all memory errors. Now the program runs perfectly fine in valgrind (no crashes, no leaks) but if I start it without valgrind it's still crashing.

Comment: @Thomas It still crashes when you run in a debugger? Then maybe you could try stepping through the code line by line until it crashes? It might be a lot of stepping, especially if it doesn't crash on the first run through the code in question, but hopefully you will see something that can give you a hint to what the problem might be.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In valgrind it doesn't crash but in gdb it does. This is how the thread currently looks like: http://pastie.org/10636461 - the output: http://pastie.org/10636462 so I already know the exact line it's crashing (the printf. The NULL check right before the printf is fine). gdb shows exactly the same stacktrace (except that the line number in think.c has changed) as shown above.

Comment: A bit more debugging: I added print statements ( http://pastie.org/10636726 ) and the result looks like `Before: 7f63d8000bb0 After: ffffffffd8000bb0` or `Before: 7f462c000bb0 After: 2c000bb0` which leads me to believe there's something writing zeros or ones partly in the memory holding the pointer address. But valgrind doesn't show any such behavior and there's no other code running in between these two print statements (the main thread is waiting for input from `fgets`/stdin and there is no other child).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your call to `freeMemory`:

```
freeMemory(think);
```

You've coded that function to take the address of the pointer to the memory to be freed, rather than the pointer itself.  So you need to call it with:

```
freeMemory(&think);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but the program is crashing before it reaches the call to `freeMemory`.

Comment: I see.  Not sure what's going on, but I also noticed that you sometimes assign a fixed `"NULL"` string to `think` before freeing it.  That will also cause a memory error.  But it looks like your problem occurs prior to that.

Comment: @Thomas And you haven't called `freeMemory` the wrong way *before* this code? You don't run your code in a loop?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, `freeMemory` is not called before. Yes, this code does run in a loop, well, more of a recursive thread. But threading also doesn't seem to be the problem. In case you want to have a look, this is my example code till now: http://pastie.org/10635991 ... it also works with the threads but does everything correctly.

Comment: @Thomas You create threads recursively, *when* do the crash happen, in the first thread? The second? After many threads? Maybe it's just resource exhaustion by creating to many threads? Oh, and you *do* free the memory you allocate in the main loop? :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I changed that so it's using just one thread with a loop inside instead but yes, it crashes when the thread runs for the first time. For now I rewrote a lot and startet to use valgrind heavily: No leaks, no race conditions but still it crashes when running without valgrind (yes, inside of valgrind it runs perfectly fine //EDIT: Yes, I also used helgrind).

Answer (score -1):

[Deleted misstated assertion]

Why not use `strcpy()`?

Comment: Look at how the OP calculates the length of the string, and how the OP copies. If there's a terminator in the original string it will be copied. But yes the OP should have used `strcpy` instead.